# Is this Stack Overflow question title correct?

Tags: questions, gerunds

I asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567251/is-reading-or-writing-directly-from-boostasiosslstreamnext-layer-bypas) on Stack Overflow with the following title:

> Is reading or writing directly from boost::asio::ssl::stream::next_layer() bypasses SSL decryption and encryption?

A friend of mine told me that the sentence isn't correct and I have to use `bypassing` instead of `bypasses` in it. Then the whole sentence will be:

> Is reading or writing directly from boost::asio::ssl::stream::next_layer() bypassing SSL decryption and encryption?

I asked another friend for his opinion and he told me the following:

> Personally I would write `would bypass`, but `bypasses` is OK. `Bypassing` is wrong because this way there is no predicate.

In his variant the whole sentence will become:

> Is reading or writing directly from boost::asio::ssl::stream::next_layer() would bypass SSL decryption and encryption?

No one of us is native speaker and I'm wondering which is the correct way?

Comment: "Does reading from or writing to `boost::...::next_layer()` bypass SSL decryption/encryption?"

Comment: @Hot Licks Yes, it sounds the best compared to the proposed variants. It seems that the auxiliary verb is wrong but all of us focused on the main verb form. :)

Comment: @Hot Licks I will accept this as answer if you write it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Does reading from or writing to `boost::...::next_layer()` bypass SSL decryption/encryption?"

Comment: I believe "Is...bypassing..." would also be correct (continuous present).